# Securely transfer api response to another server?

Tags: javascript, php, api, networking, oauth

I need to send the response of a api call to another server, is there a secure way of doing this? I need to make sure that the client server doesn't tamper with the data too.

[image]

The goal is to allow the user (with there own api key) to make a request to a 3rd party api, and securely give the response to me to verify information. This needs to be done, given that the the 3rd party api doesn't have oauth support.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you've not had a response for a month, I'll have a pop at a broad answer.

The 3rd party API server would need to store a return URL against the client's API key. When they receive a request using the client's API key they will match the key with the URL in their database and send the response to that URL instead of back to the client.

This will require cooperation with the 3rd party API provider, and implementation specifics would depend on them.

An aside, oAuth wouldn't necessarily help you here as the token generation system (that I rather assume you are referring to) is only relevant for the authentication part of any API interaction, and you didn't mention specific uses.